# Como funciona el contexto de datos en VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js

He estado pensando un poco en como VUE maneja la direcciones de acceso para la obtención de datos y métodos, ya que evita el uso de `data` y `methods` por el uso de `this`, esto me parece interesante aunque no he podido encontrar documentación al respecto, me gustaría saber como lo hace internamente, pienso que podría tener una buena implementan en otros casos.

Ejemplo:

```js
new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      mounted(){                
      
        // Como se implementa el 'data' y 'methods' a 'this' 
        console.log(this.valor);        
        this.funcion();
        
        // En vez de:
        console.log(this.data.valor);
        this.methods.funcion();
      },
      data: {
        valor: '>> valor'
      },
      methods: {
        funcion: () => console.log('>> funcion')
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Yo por lo menos no entiendo claramente que estas preguntando. Supongo que leiste la documentacion, pero estas preguntando algo mas a nivel de codigo fuente. Sobre eso viste algo?

Comment: No realmente, no he encontrado alguna referencia de este funcionamiento, actualizare la pregunta con un código de ejemplo.

Comment: ahh.. probablemente sea sugar syntasis permitida por vue. La verdad nunca me lo pregunte, habria que revisar bien que hace vue al transformar esto al js resultante...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que desea saber está en la [documentación](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/) y se resumen en dos puntos.

1. Las propiedades de [data](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data), Vue, las convertirá recursivamente en getters y setters, para obtener su valor y modificarse. Es por eso que puede acceder directamente con `this.valor` y setear con `this.valor = algo`, pero también es posible acceder a las propiedades de la otra forma, `this.$data.valor;`, notese el `$` antes.
2. **Todos** los [métodos](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods) tendrán como contexto `this` y hasta donde sé, es la única forma de acceder, no hay un `$methods` como para las propiedades de data.

**Código**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted(){                

    // Como se implementa el 'data' y 'methods' a 'this' 
    console.log(this.valor);        
    this.funcion();

    // En vez de:
    console.log(this.$data.valor);
  },
  data: {
    valor: '>> valor'
  },
  methods: {
    funcion: () => console.log('>> funcion')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```